# How to maintain the current slice selected by the user in webdatarocks report?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, webdatarocks

I am using the WebDataRocks reporting tool in asp.net core razor view, the user specifies some form inputs to filter the report with, and clicks show report to display the report, and when the user selects additional fields to be displayed ( from the report "fields" option in the report toolbox), and click show report again ( may he changed the filtration inputs), the newly selected fields disappear and display the fields based on the specified slice at the beginning, Is there a way to save the last selected fields (slice) by the user with the subsequent requests to display the report?

Comment: Can you describe your expected result a bit more clearly? Did the configuration information in [this document](https://www.webdatarocks.com/doc/slice-object/) help you?

Answer (score 0):

The Fields List does not save its state after some field or measure is added or removed. To change the slice, press the "Apply" button inside the Fields List.
Also, you can use the following API calls to implement a custom Fields List where all the changes are applied immediately:

- `getRows`, `getColumns`, `getMeasures`, `getReportFilters` - get the
  current slice configuration
- `getAllHierarchies`, `getAllMeasures` - retrieve all the data about
  fields
- `runQuery(slice)` - modify the slice in runtime. Contains
  rows, columns, measures, and    reportFilters options from the slice
  object